On Prod, Django site logs me out everytime I refresh
On local development 127.0.0.1/3000, this does not happen. However in prod (www.mydomain.com), I get logged out upon refreshing the page but I still see the cookies for sessionid and csrftoken in my browser.
I am deploying my React-Django app on AWS, we use S3 for static hosting, Cloudfront, and nginx.
Here are some snippets from our settings.py:

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mydomain.dev']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'https://www.mydomain.dev',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'https://www.mydomain.dev',
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'https://www.mydomain.dev',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'backend',
    'corsheaders',
]
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.asgi.application'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'backend.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'




What is the SESSION_ENGINE setting configured to? If it isn't configured what database are you using? And how have you deployed your application?
